# Search & replace for a string separated by whitespace upon substring match found

Tags: files, string, search, replace, delete

Below is a sample file content:

cat sample.txt

```
-server -XX:+UseParallelGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+AggressiveHeap -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=12908998 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -Xmn512m -Xss4m -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=4m -XX:-BindGCTaskThreadsToCPUs -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=20 -Dweblogic.SocketReaders=10
```

In a seperate mapping file, I'm given a list of strings one of which is `-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit`. if this string is found then it should be removed along with its value.

Thus, I wish to remove the entire entry ( along with its value ) `-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=12908998`

I'm able to remove `-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit` by replacing `-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit` to null as below:

`sed -e s/-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit//g -i sample.txt`

As regex `\S*\s` get me the entire string separated by whitespace I tried but failed with the below attempt:

`sed -e s/-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit\S*\s//g -i sample.txt`

But I'm not sure how do I remove along with its value i.e. `-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=12908998`

Desired output:

cat sample.txt

```
-server -XX:+UseParallelGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+AggressiveHeap -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -Xmn512m -Xss4m -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=4m -XX:-BindGCTaskThreadsToCPUs -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=20 -Dweblogic.SocketReaders=10
```

Comment: There's a regex for numbers too: `[:digit:]`, so `[[:digit:]]*` would match a string of digits...

Comment: I think the code you tried would have worked if you only put the the pattern in quotation marks; otherwise, your shell may be globbing on the `*`: `sed -i -e 's/-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit\S*\s//g' sample.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sed` command is working fine, you are just missing the quotes.

```
sed -e 's/-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=\S*\s//g'
```

Comment: The solution provided should work for both numeric and alpha-numerics. Kindly suggest.

Comment: the solution does not work if `-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=/log/tmp/maxlimit`

Comment: @Ashar noted. You should have that included in your initial question.